# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 14: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, utf-8

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User-010\Downloads\company_sales_data.csv')
```

When uploading file, I'm getting error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 14: invalid continuation byte

I try iso also, try encoding alo, also getting error.

I am not getting file to open for analysis.

[image]

Comment: Then your file is not encoded in UTF-8. Check its encoding first, we can't guess it

Comment: It's most likely encoded in cp1251